# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm trying to create a user-generated table that can be stored and accessed across multiple sessions on the same computer.

However, every time I try to parse the JSON string I stored in localStorage, an error pops up.

I have tried to look up other questions similar to this, but could not find anything that seemed to be the exact problem I am facing.

```
if (localStorage.length > 0) {
  students = [localStorage.getItem(JSON.parse("students"))];
  addStudentToTable();
```

This is supposed to pull the stored JSON string and convert it back into an object stored in an array, but for some reason, it can not read the JSON string that was stored.

Comment: localStorage.setItem("students",JSON.stringify([{name:"Abc"},{name:"Pqr"}]));

JSON.parse(localStorage.students);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"students" definitely is not a correct JSON, so no wonder that the engine protests at `JSON.parse("students")`.

You probably want something like

```
  students = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));
```